# XPath/HTMLAgilityPack problems

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to get player lists from here:

http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201105090BOS.html

To do that for the first table, I use the following:

```
HtmlNode reboundsNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='sortable stats_table']/tbody[1]");
    foreach(HtmlNode node in reboundsNode.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        // Get the 'td's.
    }
```

I had to split it into two lines, because `"//table[@class='sortable stats_table']/tbody[1]/tr"` selected `tr`s from all of the table bodies instead of just the first one. Does anyone know why?

I also have problems when getting the data from the second table (actually table number 3 in the source since there are tables 2 and 4 that are invisible in the default view). When I select `"//table[@class='sortable stats_table']"`, it shows that there are four tables, but when I do `"//table[@class='sortable stats_table'][3]"`, it finds nothing (I get an unbound object exception when I try to use the result. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because XPath [] is not a number of table body, but condition , so 1 mean always true - try this - it will select from first tbody

```
 //table[@class='sortable stats_table']/tbody[position() = 1]/tr
```

Second question

```
 //table[@class='sortable stats_table'][3]
```

This is invalid xpath - correct way to write this is

```
 //table[@class='sortable stats_table' and position() = 3]
```

Note: position starts from 1 not from 0 and ends at elements count.

Comment: Weird. So why did the [N] notation work for me for multiple other expressions?

Comment: i don't know (maybe some MS option or so on), but it is invalid for XPath , it is valid for JavaScript, C, PHP ...

Comment: [N] subcript is indeed valid for XPath, e.g. `para[1] selects the first para child of the context node`  See
 http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev